# powershell: Copy files of type AND their path values

Tags: powershell

I need to copy all my fileserver psts to another location with their folder paths.
I did the following

```
Get-ChildItem D: -recurse -include *.pst | copy-item -destination z:\
```

But this resulted in copies of like filenames being created.

I need the copy to write out the path name (its home folders so the pathname will help with easy ownership)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Give an example of what you want

Comment: sure for e.g. source = D:\somefolder\anotherfolder\some.pst , destination =  "same as source path"\some.pst , does this help?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the -recurse and -force flag on copy-item.  It might create the folder structure.  If it doesn't, you can use New-item to create that structure with a bit of work.  If you're looking for an answer like that (i.e. you want folder structure copied as well) update your question with more detail and you'll get an answer focused on that.

What I would do, if I was just looking for a unique name for each PST, is to convert the full name to a file name on Z:, like so:

```
$psts = Get-ChildItem D:\ -recurse -include "*.pst"

$psts | % {
     Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination ($_.FullName.Replace("D:\","Z:\").Replace("\","-"))
}
```

It might be messy, but it should be unique.

Comment: Thanks - don't know why I did not try this first time round , good old robocopy works like a charm! robocopy c:\test\ c:\test1 *.pst /e

Comment: Using PowerShell makes me dislike using standard cmdline utilities that don't generate rich output like cmdlets do.  Until I try to do things like add service dependencies (sc.exe and almost impossible with PowerShell) or takeown and icacls.  Some things just need to be simple.